# eliminate strings from a file and print the rest

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed, data-processing

I have two files:

file1.dat

```
  1.01    
  2.01    
  3.01    
  4.01    
  5.01    
  5.02    
  6.01    
  7.01    
  8.01    
  9.01
```

And another file, file2.dat as follow:

```
0006.01
0008.01
```

What I want is to eliminate from the file1.dat the numbers listed in the file2.dat, to do that I made a bash script as follow:

```
#!/bin/bash

touch file1.dat
touch file2.dat

for f in $(< file2.dat)
do
  sed "/$f/d" file1.dat > output.dat
done
```

But actually the result is that the output.dat is equal to file1.dat, thus I don't know if, maybe, the problem are the zeros in front of the numbers in the file2.dat.

Thanks to everybody.

**[SOLVED]**

The problem was due to the space/tab at the beginning of the file. I solve it with the followed bash:

1) I rewrite the file2.dat with a very small f90 code to eliminate the zeros in front of the reals,

2) I launch the script to eliminate from file1.dat the tab/spaces and then the awk command:

```
cat file1.dat | tr -d " \t\r" > file1_1.dat
cat file2_rewrit.dat | tr -d " \t\r" > file2_rewrit_1.dat
awk 'FNR==NR {a[$0];next} !($0 in a)' file2_rewrit_1.dat  file1_1.dat > output.txt
```

Comment: So file1.dat output should look: 5.02?

Comment: No, actually should look like: 
`  1.01    
  2.01    
  3.01    
  4.01    
  5.01    
  5.02    
  7.01    
  9.01`
Whitout the lines with 6.01 and 8.01

Comment: Ok, add before sed f=$(echo $f | awk '{x=$0+0;print x}')

Comment: Do you have a fixed layout? I do not want to delete 12.0123 when file2 has 0002.01. You want something with `^` and `$`.

Comment: @Noproblem unfortunatelly it doesn't work the otuput.txt file looks like the file1.dat :(

Comment: Here is a Sample for this Question. The duplicate Answer does NOT answer this Question with different numeric notation.

# cat file1.dat file2.dat | sed 's/^[0]\{1,99\}//g' |sort |uniq -c | sed 's/^[ ]\{0,99\}//g' | grep "^1 " | cut -d' ' -f2